# In Python ... how can I extract name and ext from the .txt file

Tags: python

My file is just like this.

```
  label0/index.jpeg 0

  label1/index.jpeg 1
```

my code is

```
 def add_ext_name(cls, path, ext_name): 
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))
    added = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), name + ext_name + ext)
    return added
```

The error is

```
 def basename(p):
   """Returns the final component of a pathname"""
     p = os.fspath(p)
     sep = _get_sep(p)
     i = p.rfind(sep) + 1

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageProperty
```

where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: Mind that `basename` is already a function defined in `os.path`.

Comment: your code seems ok (at least the one shown). The issue is probably in the caller which passes an object and not a string...

Comment: Could you just specify your expected output?